# Joining string with no NULL values using lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lambda, linq-expressions

I am trying to return a JSON result in one of my ASP.NET MVC methods as below:

```
Dictionary<string, List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>> resp = 
    MyMethod(params);

return Json(new 
{ 
    result = res, 
    message = string.Join(";", resp.Select(v => v.Value.First().ErrorMessage))
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

`resp` dictionary could be empty or not. `resp` can also be `null`. When it is not empty and not `null`, a key-value pair could contain a `null` for the value, e.g. key="errors" but its corresponding value set to `null`. So taking into account this, I want `message` field to contain a semicolon-separated list containing all non `null` dictionary values. If resp is empty, `null`, or all dictionary values are `null`, "message" will contain an empty string.

Examples, possible scenarios:

1. When resp is an empty string or NULL => message will be an empty
   string
2. When resp is not empty/null, examples:

   - {"errors","blabla"},{"warn",NULL} => message will be "blabla"
   - {"errors","blabla"},{"errors","blablabla"},{"warn",NULL} => message will be "blabla;blablabla"
   - {"errors",NULL},{"warn",NULL} => message will be an empty string

How can I do it using a lambda expression to obtain these results?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I tried above indicated. See string assigned to message filed in the anonymous type. Also I do not know how to face with the possible scenarios indicated.

Comment: I don't think your description is quite right given the declarations. You have a dictionary and each entry can have a list of results. You'll need to flatten those results

Comment: In your point #1, `resp` cannot be an empty string, since it's a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we shouldn't need to worry about empty lists or dictionaries, but null values take some extra checking. You also have a collection of collections, so to flatten that you can use SelectMany.

Just focus on getting the message, you don't need to do this all in one line of code.

```
   var message = resp==null ? "" : string.Join(";", 
    resp.Where(l => l.Value != null)
        .SelectMany( l=> 
          l.Value.Where(vr => vr != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(vr.ErrorMessage))
           .Select( vr => vr.ErrorMessage )));
```

That should give you the message. Sorry, I didn't compile and run it, but it should have all the checks for null and the flattening that you need.

Comment: Great, and how can I adapt it if I want to get the first one not null and not empty? For example If I have {"errors","blabla01"},{"errors","blablabla"},{"warn",NULL} => message will be "blabla01" I have tried to modify your expression in order to add First but without success

Comment: @NetMage not necessary. Checking for a null value accomplishes that

Comment: You should be getting "blabla01;blablabla" in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the `Values` property (which is the `List<ValidationResult>`) of `res` directly, and you can simply select all those where the `ErrorMessage` is not null or empty:

```
return Json(new
{
    result = res,
    message = resp == null ? string.Empty : string.Join(";", 
        resp.Values.SelectMany(value => value
            .Where(validationResult => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationResult?.ErrorMessage))
            .Select(validationResult => validationResult.ErrorMessage)))
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```